# Probability of pairing 20 questions to 20 answers correctly

Tags: probability

I am working with a problem from a statistics book as follows:

You have 20 questions and 20 answers. You are supposed to pair correct answer to the correct question. In the book they say that the probability of guessing and getting everything right is 1/400. However doesn`t order matter here? Is the answer not 1/20! ?

Apologies in advance for the dumb question.

Comment: Does every answer pair with a unique question?  If so, then I'd agree with $\frac 1{20!}$.

Comment: Can you post the problem exactly as asked in the book?

Comment: If there is only one question and one answer which fit (and this pair has to be found) then we would have $\frac{1}{400}$. But as formulated , noone would inteprete it this way.

Comment: I suppose the book was not able to (statistically) pair correctly the correct one answer for this one question. Look for an other question with an odd answer of $1/20!$...

Comment: I am translating from norwegian but it goes like this : 

You are taking an exam and are given 20 questions and 20 answers, where you must put together the correct answers and questions. What is the probability of getting everything correct if you are purely guessing?

It goes something like that, but I cannot believe that the answer is 1/400.

Comment: $1/400$ is the probability to choose one correct question and its answer. Could it be asked something along these lines?

Comment: I do not think so. It clearly asks " what is the probability of getting every answer right by purely guessing" ... Full question in original language ( norwegian) : 

Du tar en eksamen og får oppgitt 20 spørsmål og 20 svar, der du skal sette sammen riktige spørsmål og svar. Hva er sannsynligheten for å få alt riktig ved ren tipping?

Answer (score 2):

Let's see the intuition with 3 questions and 3 answers. Favorable outcome is q1a1q2a2q3a3.

All outcomes are
q1a1q2a2q3a3
q1a1q2a3q3a2
q1a2q2a1q3a3
q1a2q2a3q3a1
q1a3q2a1q3a2
q1a3q2a2q3a1

Probability of right pairing is 1/6. Similarly for 2 pairs, it's 1/2 and for 4 pairs, it's 1/24

So you're right about 1/n!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Srini, however you can simply prove it with 20 questions right away, without having to just use smaller examples. Let’s start by calculating the total number of possibilities. For the first question, there are $20$ possible answers we can match to it. As for the second, we can use the twenty minus the one we used for the first question, or $19$ options. This keeps going until there is one option for the last question. This is of course $20!$ possibilities. If one works, there is a $\dfrac{1}{20!}$ chance of getting it all right as you said. To go more into detail, if an answer overlaps or there is the same answer $x$ times, you will have $\dfrac{x!}{20!}$